# FreeNAS FTP Error: 425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: truenas, ftp

When I try to connect to SSL enabled proftpd as installed on Freenas 8.3.0, I see my client feedback output saying that AUTH TLS is working, the connection goes encrypted (as confirmed by Wireshark) and everything goes as far as:

```
[2] MLSD
[2] 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for MLSD
```

After a while of nothing happening I get:

```
[2] 425 Unable to build data connection: Operation not permitted
```

The exact same configuration, less the SSL related directives (unchecking 'Enable SSL' in the FreeNAS GUI), works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with a bit of both pieces of software. Your TLS log for proftpd will probably be saying something like this:

```
mod_tls/2.4.1[9592]: client did not reuse SSL session, rejecting data connection (see TLSOption NoSessionReuseRequired)
```

So the directive that is needed to resolve the issue is `TLSOptions NoSessionReuseRequired`. BUT, you can't simply add this to directives to append to the conf file in the FreeNAS GUI, because interally it already uses a `TLSOptions` directive and subsequent usage of this directive is ignored (ie your addition).

A future version of proftpd will resolve this by permitting multiple declarations of `TLSOptions`. Or, the FreeNAS GUI needs to either include `NoSessionReuseRequired` under its Enabled SSL umbrella of directives or add a checkbox if such a thing isn't always desired (requiring session re-use saves resources so if all your clients support it, it's preferred).

In the meantime, navigate to `/usr/local/etc/` and edit `proftpd.conf`. Find the line:

```
TLSOptions NoCertRequest
```

and make it look like:

```
TLSOptions NoCertRequest NoSessionReuseRequired
```

I created a bug report on the matter. Check it out here:
https://bugs.freenas.org/issues/1910